# how to convert multi valued CSV to Json

Tags: python, json, linux, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with 4 columns data as below.

```
type,MetalType,Date,Acknowledge     
Metal,abc123451,2018-05-26,Success
Metal,abc123452,2018-05-27,Success
Metal,abc123454,2018-05-28,Failure
Iron,abc123455,2018-05-29,Success
Iron,abc123456,2018-05-30,Failure
```

( I just provided header in the above example data but in my case i dont have header in the data)

how can i convert above csv file to Json in the below format...

1st Column : belongs to --> `"type": "Metal"`

2nd Column : `MetalType: "values" : "value": "abc123451"`

3rd column : `"Date": "values":"value": "2018-05-26"`

4th Column : `"Acknowledge": "values":"value": "Success"`

and remaining all columns are default values.

As per below format ,

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "XXXXXXX",
      "type": "Metal",
      "data": {
        "attributes": {
          "MetalType": {
            "values": [
              {
                "source": "XYZ",
                "locale": "Australia",
                "value": "abc123451"
              }
            ]
          },
          "Date": {
            "values": [
              {
                "source": "XYZ",
                "locale": "Australia",
                "value": "2018-05-26"
              }
            ]
          },
          "Acknowledge": {
            "values": [
              {
                "source": "XYZ",
                "locale": "Australia",
                "value": "Success"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
      }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: @ Entities  is my main tag and all the records should be repeated inside the entities tag. Is that possible ..?

Comment: You are expected to make an effort. Please show your code and state where you are having trouble. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158334) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww .. I am completely new to python ,  so thats why i was asking in this way.

Answer (score -1):

Even though jww is right, I built something for you:

I import the csv using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

then I create a template for the dictionaries you want to add:

```
d_json = {"entities": []}
template = {
      "id": "XXXXXXX",
      "type": "",
      "data": {
        "attributes": {
          "MetalType": {
            "values": [
              {
                "source": "XYZ",
                "locale": "Australia",
                "value": ""
              }
            ]
          },
          "Date": {
            "values": [
              {
                "source": "XYZ",
                "locale": "Australia",
                "value": ""
              }
            ]
          },
          "Acknowledge": {
            "values": [
              {
                "source": "XYZ",
                "locale": "Australia",
                "value": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
      }
```

Now you just need to fill in the dictionary:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    d = template
    d['type'] = df['type'][i]
    d['data']['attributes']['MetalType']['values'][0]['value'] = df['MetalType'][i]
    d['data']['attributes']['Date']['values'][0]['value'] = df['Date'][i]
    d['data']['attributes']['Acknowledge']['values'][0]['value'] = df['Acknowledge'][i]

    d_json['entities'].append(d)
```

I know my way of iterating over the df is kind of ugly, maybe someone knows a cleaner way.

Cheers!